# What is the Big-O of a nested loop, where the outer loop is n^2

Tags: big-o, nested-loops

```
for(int i = 1; i < n **2; i++) 
{    
   for(int j = 1; j < i; j++)    
   {
     s = s;    
   } 
}
```

Since the Big O of the outter loop is O(n^2) would it still be multiplied by the inner loop making the total Big O notation be n(n^2) -> O(n^3)?

Comment: If you changed your inner loop condition to `j < n`, you would have a O(n^3) algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the outer loop, i can take values from 1 to n^2. Then for each of those values, the inner loop goes from 1 to i. The number of operations performed for i=1 is 1, i=2 is 2, ..., i = n^2 is n^2.

So the total number of operations is the sum for i from 1 to n^2 of i. This is a well known [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) which has the closed form of (n^2)(n^2 + 1)/2 and that is O(n^4)

Comment: Okay so I follow up until you do the two functions multiplied together divided by two.  Why do you divide by two in this case?

Comment: @ryandonohue Chad is summing all of the numbers from 1 to n^2.  The formula for summing numbers like this is n(n+1)/2.  https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/groups/tatami/kumo/exs/sum/  That's where the "divide by two" comes from.

Comment: I edited to include a link to the relevant series, but you can also think about it yourself. If you take the first half of the series (1, 2, 3,...) and add it to the second half (n^2, n^2-1, n^2-2, ...) what you end up with is (n^2/2)(n^2+1) which is another way of writing (n^2)(n^2+1)/2